# Double quotes in HTML form (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=" <?php setValue( "firstName" ) ?> " />
```

The problem is, the value attribute reaches the first quote `<?php setValue(` as a value of the input field. How to deal with it?

Comment: I think the code is right and should work. However you can use `'` instead.

Comment: Given the answers below, are you sure you're running this as `.php` and inside a PHP environment such as `http://localhost` and not as `file:///` and/or an `.html` file? I hope you're going to reply to comments here and not just answers.

Comment: what does this function do? `setValue()`. Plus, is that JS or PHP?

Comment: `function setValue($fieldName){
  if( isset( $_POST([$fieldName]))){
   echo $_POST([$fieldName]);
  }
 }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're right, i did! I did it with `file:///` ... well, now it's showing an error on the function `setValue`: "Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call"

Comment: your question's content does not support the new error you've posted in comments.

Comment: okay, thank you! I'll deal with it

Answer (score 2):

Try concat :

```
<input type="text" value="' . <?php setValue('firstName') ?> . '"/>
```

Comment: I've tried already but it outputs `<?php setValue( \`

Comment: here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ShiroiOkami/km9e5r9v/

Answer (score 2):

You could use an echo this way

```
<?php echo  '<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="'.  
                 setValue( "firstName" ). '" />' ; ?>
```

Comment: no, this didn't work

Comment: @ShiroiOkami what's mean don't work .. you have an error .?. or the value is not  the string  "firstname" ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that this displays only  ' ?>;  somehow... instead of the field

Comment: @ShiroiOkami   . answer  updated  wrong ; position

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ShiroiOkami/km9e5r9v/

Comment: @scaisEdge See my comments under the question; that's what I think is happening here.

Comment: @scaisEdge [And I was right...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070442/double-quotes-in-html-form-php#comment67416345_40070442) being *"you're right, i did! I did it with file:///"*. So I closed the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   Ok. thanks ... Right ..    ..

Comment: @scaisEdge welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think your data is return firstName value or whatever by function setValue. You have to echo your value that is

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=" <?php echo setValue( "firstName" ) ?> " />
```

and your code is correct. Than use

```
<?php echo  '<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="'.  
             setValue( "firstName" ). '" />';  ?>
```

Comment: yes, I thought so too but this outputs `<?php echo setValue(` into the field

Comment: @ShiroiOkami Sorry, I did not understand

Comment: it displays the field and the value inside is `<?php echo setValue(`

Comment: @ShiroiOkami check again I have changed it.

Comment: I've checked and now it prints only last characters `'; ?>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ShiroiOkami/km9e5r9v/

Comment: did you have php, means jsfiddle.net only support javascript, html and css.